# Windows Service Account Log on as Batch doesnt set appdata

Tags: windows

I have a small C# console application the does some logic that I want to run as a daily task. This applicaiton saves some information in the user settings (%appdata%\local) to remember some information for the next run. I use a .bat script and the Task Scheduler to run this app nightly under the credentials of a service account. This account has the "log on as batch job" permissions on the machine.

I noticed that when I run as an admin user, the user settings are created in %appdata%\local and reflect in the next time the app is run. However for the service account. It looks like these settings are never written, as the folder inside %appdata%\local isnt there. The script outputs logs when it runs and moves some files around, so I can see that its working, but I can tell that the user settings are not being saved due to the output along with the fact that the settings files aren't there.

Is there some issue with the "log on as batch" permission setting that prevents writing to the %appdata% directory? Any help is appreciated.